# Jquery is(":visible") on a class

Tags: jquery, class, visible

At the moment I am doing this:

```
bl = !$("#divModal1").is(":visible") &&
    !$("#divModal2").is(":visible") &&
    !$("#divModal3").is(":visible") &&
    !$("#divModal4").is(":visible") &&
    !$("#divModal5").is(":visible");
```

where divModal# are all divs who share the same class class="divModalDialog".

Is there a better way of doing this by checking the class rather than each individual one?

Basically bl must be false if one or more of these divModal# is showing.

Comment: `$('.modalClass').is(':visible')`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) documentation:

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return `true` if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

Therefore, simply using the class name suffices, since `.is(":visible")` will return true if any of them are visible.

```
bl = !$(".divModalDialog").is(":visible");
```

Comment: Or if you wan't a little more understable for the anybody you could use this(is the same):
b1 = $(".divModalDialog").is(":hidden");

Answer (score 1):

[`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo class can be used for getting visible elements.

```
bl = ! $(".divModalDialog:visible").length > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if all `divs` are not `visible` you can do this:

```
var modalDialogsCount = $(".divModalDialog").length;

var returnValue = modalDialogsCount == !$(".divModalDialog:visible").length ? true : false;
```

This code checks if all `divModalDialog` are not `visible` and returns `true` if it's true.